# loop or previous error loading module in corana using lua language

Tags: lua

i need help to solve the problem. i really cant know why this error occur.
i use this code to develop a tourism app for my final year project. please help me to solve this

```js
local accomodation = require( "accomodation")
local function onComplete( event )
 local action = event.action
 if "clicked" == event.action then
  if 2 == event.index then
   -- Open url if "Learn More" was clicked by the user
   system.openURL( "http://www.trivago.com.my/?iPathId=74807&iGeoDistanceItem=0&aDateRange%5Barr%5D=2016-04-17&aDateRange%5Bdep%5D=2016-04-18&iRoomType=7&cpt=7480703&iViewType=0&bIsSeoPage=false&bIsSitemap=false&" )
  end
 elseif "cancelled" == event.action then
  -- our cancelAlert timer function dismissed the alert so do nothing
 end
end

-- Show alert
local alert = native.showAlert( "GoPenang", "You will be directed to trivago.com", { "Cancel", "Ok" }, onComplete )

-- Dismisses alert after 10 seconds
local function cancelAlert()
 native.cancelAlert( alert )
end

function scene:createScene(event)
   local group = self.view
   end
function scene: enterScene(event)
    local group = self.view
 end
function scene:exitScene(event)
local group = self.view
end
function scene:destroyScene(event)
local group = self.view
end

timer.performWithDelay( 10000, cancelAlert )

scene:addEventListener("createScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("enterScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("exitScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("destroyScene",scene)
return scene
```

this is my accomodation code. the error will appear like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNi6z.png)

Comment: Why are you invoking `require("accomodation")` inside `accomodation.lua`?  Recursion is a great power.  Use it wisely.

Answer (score -1):

The error message says that it can't load the "accomodation" module. I don't know what that module does, but in the very first line you are writing

```
local accomodation = require( "accomodation")
```

That piece of code is trying to load the accomodation module - which you seem to never use anywhere in the posted code. Try removing that line and see what follows.

Comment: i already did that but a new error has occur : attempt to index global 'scene' (a nil value)..what should i do?

Comment: I have absolutely no experience with corona - I only described what the error message means since it's a Lua error. If you want to build a scene in corona, you seem to do something like this:

    local composer = require( "composer" )
    local scene = composer.newScene()

- which I found at [coronalabs.com](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/06/03/tutorial-understanding-the-composer-api/). Maybe you can find some more pointers there.